# Magento : Invoice : draw table on product list

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, invoice

I am not so good at Magento pdf, Any one who applied this please help me. In a Invoice PDF i need to draw table for the products list or item list,[image]

it would very great if any one helps me out with this.

Comment: have you tried something:??

Comment: no i have no idea of how to??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all overwrite `invoice.php` in local (which is in `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice`)

Before call `_drawItem` define a variable for `$startTable=$this->y;`

After `_drawItem` function

```
$page = $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);
                $page->setLineColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
                $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
                $page->drawLine(25, $this->y + 12.5, 570, $this->y + 12.5);

$page->setLineColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));

$page->setLineWidth(0.5);

$page->drawLine(25, $startTable,25,$this->y+12.5); 

$page->drawLine(185, $startTable,185, $this->y+12.5);

$page->drawLine(275, $startTable,275,$this->y+12.5);

$page->drawLine(345, $startTable,345,$this->y+12.5);

$page->drawLine(460, $startTable,460,$this->y+12.5);

$page->drawLine(570, $startTable,570, $this->y+12.5);
```